# Chars being cut out of "custom" toupper statement in C

Tags: c, string, uppercase

This is my first time writing in C and I have to write a code that does to upper on a string without actually using to upper.

I have done this however it only works up to 8 characters for some reason....
-----
Here is the input:
hello hello hello 
hello
-----
Here is the output:
Copy: hello hello hello hello
;▒
The capitalized string is HELLO HEp▒▒▒
The original string is hello hello hello hello

```
#include <stdio.h>

int strLength(char* str){
     int count;
     for(count=0;str[count] != '\n';count++){}
     return count;
}

char* copyStr(char* str,char* str2){
     for(int i=0;str[i] != '\n';i++){
          char n = str[i];
          str2[i] = n;
     }
     str2[strLength(str)] = '\n';
     return str2;
}

char* upper(char* str){
     char str2[100];
     for(int i=0;str[i] != '\n';i++){
         int current = str[i];
         if((current >= 97) && (current <= 122)){
              char new = str[i];
              str2[i] = new-32;
          }
          else{
               str2[i] = current;
          }
    }
    char* str3 = str2;
    return str3;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv){
     char input[100];
     char inputcopy[100];

     //get the input string
     printf("Enter string: ");
     fgets(input, 100, stdin);

     copyStr(input,inputcopy);
     printf("Copy: %s\n", inputcopy);
     printf("The capitalized string is %s\n",upper(inputcopy));
     printf("The original string is %s",input);
}
```

Comment: Hey, good first question. I can see there's some unused/unrelated code in your question. It helps us bring you answers quicker if you remove the irrelevant parts.  These short verifiable code snippets are known as [MVCE's or MCVE's or MRE's](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). The only 2 functions we care about here are `upper` and `main`.

Comment: In C, the end of strings is marked with `\0`, not `\n`. Your code is reading/writing past end of strings and into random memory.

Comment: @byxor Okay, thank you for the advise

Comment: Since you are passing `inputcopy` to `upper()`, just make the changes to upper-case within the `inputcopy` array itself, no need to declare another array. Also don't do `if((current >= 97) && (current <= 122)){` instead make it readable by using the character literals, e.g. `if((current >= 'a') && (current <= 'z')){` (much easier to read)

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin How would I include inputcopy into upper() if inputcopy is declared after upper()?

Comment: It's not declared after `upper`, it's declared (and defined) with `char inputcopy[100];` and filled with `copyStr(input,inputcopy);` (after you fix the nul-termination there), it is ready to go when passed as a parameter to `upper(inputcopy))`, where you then simply `return str;` to make the string converted to upper available through the function return.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin Okay I understand what you are saying now. I did this and it works now. Thank you!

Comment: Good deal. Glad you got it sorted out. Here is a comparison with some additional thoughts [C - To Upper - Manual](https://susepaste.org/69091950) Note: `inputcopy` contains the upper-case conversion after `upper()` is called.

Answer (score 2):

Obvious problems:

- not NUL terminating the copy in `copyStr`
- returning a pointer to a local variable in `upper`

---

In C, you can't pass (as arguments) or return (as a return value) strings "directly" as they are not value types -- instead you must pass or return a pointer.  Whenever you deal with pointers, you need to worry about the lifetime of the things pointed at, as if you use the pointer after the lifetime of the pointee has ended, you get undefined behavior.

So in order to "return" a string from a function, you must actually return a pointer to something that has a lifetime that extends after the function has returned (which means it can't be a pointer to a local var of the function).  There are generally three way to arrange for that to happen:

1. pass a pointer to where to put the resulting string as an additional argument (this is what you do with your `copyStr` function)
2. use malloc to allocate dynamic space for the string and return a pointer to that.
3. return a pointer to a static (global) string.

Each of these has its own drawbacks:

1. the caller has to know how big a string is going to be returned (to create the object that it passes the pointer of) before it even makes the call.  Often this is impossible or requires allocating a "worst case" large string or has the danger of overrunning the buffer (causing UB).  At the least you often need a second additional argument to specify the size of the buffer.
2. The caller needs to "take charge" of the returned memory and ensure that it gets freed properly.  This becomes part of the implicit contract between caller and callee but is frequently not documented, so is a common source of memory leaks
3. All calls will generally share the same static global, so it's not reentrant or thread-safe.

Comment: If I want to return a copy of the original string (which is upper cased) what should I return? When I tried to return str2 it gave me the error "function returns address of local variable"

Comment: In C, you can't really write a function that returns a string the way you would in languages with memory management. You either have to return an allocated string and rely on the caller to free it later, or else have the caller allocate the string and pass its address and length into the function.